# Assign a function delegate that returns an anonymous type to a variable

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-types, lambda

The code below is valid:

```
IEnumerable<SomeThing> things = ...;

// map type SomeThing to a new anonymous type, resulting in a strongly typed 
// sequence based on an anon type

var newList = things.Select(item =>
    {
        return new
        {
            ID = item.ID,
            DateUpdatedOrCreated = ((DateTime)(item.DateUpdated ??
                     item.DateCreated)).ToShortDateString(),
            Total = item.Part1 + item.Part2
        };
    });
```

newList now appears in Visual Studio as `IEnumerable<'a>` and is strongly typed with the anonymous type created in the function. That is so cool.

What I can't seem to do is figure out a way to assign just the lambda expression (and not the enumeration) to an implicitly typed variable. Even though the compiler has no problem with the anonymous type in the context above, if I try (say)

```
var func = (SomeThing item)=> {
        return new { ... };
    };
```

I get the error "Cannot assign lambda expression to implicitly-typed local variable".  This seems a strange compiler limitation; unless I am missing something, the types are just as non-ambiguous in the 2nd example as they are in the first first: both type parameters are well defined.

Is there any way to do this? Since it's an anonymous type, of course, I don't have any way to use a type to assign it explicitly, so it seems I'd be stuck with making a class for the output type if not.

*Update*

Shortly after going about my merry way with Jon Skeet's answer, I found a similar dilemma instantiating classes. In case it's not obvious, the same trick can be used to create strongly typed classes using inferred anonymous types.

```
class Processor<T,U>
{
    public Processor(Func<T,U> func) {

    }
}

// func is a delegate with anon return type created using method in answer below

var instance = new Processor(func);   // does not compile! Requires type arguments!
```

cannot be created directly, but can be created in much the same way as the trick below:

```
public static Processor<T,U> Create<T,U>(Func<T,U> func) {
    return new Processor<T,U>(func);
}

var instance = Processor.Create(func);   // all good
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it via type inference:

```
var func = BuildFunc((SomeThing item) => {
    return new { ... };
});

...

static Func<TSource, TResult> BuildFunc<TSource, TResult>(
    Func<TSource, TResult> function) {
    return function;
}
```

Note that `BuildFunc` doesn't really do anything - it just provides the method call needed to get the compiler to do type inference for the generic type arguments for `Func<,>` - it adds the information that you're interested in `Func<,>`, basically - that's information which can't be specified as part of a variable declaration, without also specifying the type arguments.

Comment: This works because type inference for generics is smarter than type inference for `var`. (I assume jon might be able to explain why even though I can't.)

Comment: Good answer. Additional info: This works because you don't need to specify the variable's type here. The compiler can't just infer the type for the variable because there are multiple delegate types it could choose from.

Comment: @Servy: It's not really a matter of being smarter as such - it's a matter of being able to specify that you want a `Func` delegate, but specifying that generically.

Comment: This is awesome! It works perfectly. I am still a bit surprised that the compiler understands the complex case but not the simple one without any help, but this is easy enough and much better than making a single use class.

Comment: OK I understand why the linq query works and this doesn't, but is there a rationale for the compiler not just assuming a `Func` delegate? What else would it be valid to assign that to?

Comment: @jamietre It could  be any delegate type (other than Func), or an `Expression`

Comment: @jamietre: Any other kind of delegate type (or expression tree type) with the right signature. There's nothing magical about `Func<,>` - it's just a commonly-used delegate type.